# Constants in ultraproduct are well-defined

Tags: model-theory, filters

When defining ultraproduct it is defined to be product of domains of models $A_\xi$ modulus the equivalence relation by ultrafilter on index set. The relation on the product are defined by $(a_0/_{\mathcal U}, \dots, a_n/_{\mathcal U}) \in R$ iff $\{\xi : (a_0(\xi), \dots, a_n(\xi))\in R_\xi\}$ where $R_\xi$ is relation on model with domain $A_\xi$ and similar for the function.

I define the constant $C \in \prod_{\xi \in X}A_\xi / \mathcal U$ as $C = (\prod_\xi C_\xi)/\mathcal U$ where $C_\xi$ is the constant in model with the domain $A_\xi$. How to show it is well-defined?

Comment: What do you mean by well defined? You named an element of the domain of the ultraproduct. How can it not be well defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no well-definedness issue at all. If $C$ is a constant **symbol** in the language $L$, then the interpretation $C_{\xi}$ of  $C$ in the model with domain $A_{\xi}$ is uniquely defined. So the "sequence" $(C_{\xi})$, what you call $\prod_{\xi} C_{\xi}$, is uniquely determined, and hence so is $(\prod_{\xi} C_{\xi})/\mathcal{U}$

The situation is different with say a unary function symbol $f$ of the language $L$. For there we define $f$ at $(\prod_{\xi} a_{\xi})/\mathcal{U}$ is defined in terms of the $f(a_{\xi})$.  It is conceivable that different choices of representatives  $\prod_{\xi} a_{\xi}$ and $\prod_{\xi} a_{\xi}'$ yield different results. Easily, they don't, but this has to be checked.

Comment: Thank you for good answer. It is exercise I found when looking for ultraproducts. It is Ex. 13.24 on this [Google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=70jn3KS6qlkC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q&f=false). Is it trick question? I don't knwo the book.

Comment: @dolan: The well-definedness part is certainly simpler. Maybe trick question, maybe slip.

Comment: I thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. The notation used in the online book is perhaps more complicated than necessary. It will be useful for example to think of an ultrafilter as a two-valued (finitely additive) "measure." Then you can replace $\{\xi: a_{\xi}=b_{\xi}\}\in \mathcal{U}$ by $a=b$ a.e.

Comment: I like the quantifier notation $(\mathscr{U}\xi)(a_\xi=b_\xi)$.